# 400 BadRequest: Content-Length is not a number

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am having a **400 badRequest: Content Length is not a number** after changing my url in the fetch API call from "https://127.0.0.1:8080/getCookie" to "https://127.0.0.1:8080/endpoint/getCookie".

note: I am not specifying the content-length in the fetch api call.

I don't see issue same as Content Length is not a number in the internet.

By the way, the call was working on firefox but not in chrome and Microsoft edge.

Does anyone encounter 400 badRequest: Content Length is not a number issue?

Comment: Use your browser "Network" developer tool to examine the actual request headers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe have special settings for each browser, you mentioned that chrome and edge (chromium) get this occurs, so could you using the Network tab in Debug tool (F12) to view the request?

Beside that, could you log this request in the backend side ? For example, console.log(req).....Some browser might attach other information (such as cookie) in each request (but not for all).